# How to make a variable from django server clickable and open to new tab

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

```
<td>{{variable.atr}}</td>
```

How to make above element clickable and open new tab? Thanks

Comment: This is a JavaScript problem not Django's

Comment: You mean like an href?

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
<td><a href="xxx" target="_blank">{{variable.atr}}</a></td>
```